# Blank screen after installing new graphics card NVIDIA quadro FX 580 on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

Secondhand card, no instructions or installation CD

I plug the card in, and start the computer, I get blank screens on
a) my onboard video
b) all ports of the new graphics card (NVIDIA Quadro FX 580.

Based on my readying, my hypothesis is that Windows is trying to make use of the new card, and so is disable the onboard video. Yet without the drivers for the new card, it cannot output from the new card.

Downloaded drivers from here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_fx_580_us.html
(Technical specs available one tabs)
Didn't give me drivers, gave me a drivers installer.
Driver installer will not function without video card plugged in.
But when I plug the card in, I cannot see to install the card...
Onboard video is a VGA straight off the motherboard.
I need the Nvidia card so I can have dual monitors--onboard provides only a single output.
Machine is getting kind of old---from 2011.

Using F2 to get to the Bios, not option to disable onboard video.

Comment: Maybe you can find settings within BIOS, to use internal graphics? I also guess removing the card and boot, can bring you forward.

Comment: First i'd ask - what's your internal card? It might likely be faster than the ancient Quadro.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to tech support, issue appears to be user error. 
Multiple output video cards have a sequence of outputs, and it appears that only the primary output is active when you initially install the card (D'oh).

...Which did not fix the problem.

Tested monitor
Tested cable.
Tested alternate video card, copy of prior card.
PCI slot works.
Will now try card in another computer.
Still not sure how to determine if it's the card...or the lack of drivers for the card.

Comment: I'd still wonder how a 10-year-old card is going to be faster than the built-in video, these days...

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't stand up to any halfway modern built-in graphics.  It gets its behind handed to it by any CPU with Intel HD 4000 graphics and is just about on par with an HD 3000 based CPU: http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=1608&cmp[]=2&cmp[]=26

Comment: Yup - I have that site on speed dial ;)